# Where can i find samples of 3d models in Silverlight for windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, xna, windows-phone

This video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CL1bH5-MDU says that it is posible to mix Xna and silverlight for mango, where can i finde resources? i want to import an 3d model to my silverlight app, like the avatar in xbox live hub, how can i make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Silverlight and XNA Frameworks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402528%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[How to: Combine Silverlight and the XNA Framework in a Windows Phone application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: The problem is not about finding 3d models, it's about integrating silverlight + xna. In the mix 2011, Microsoft announced that it was going to be a silverlight version supporting xna, but i cannot find any resources. Thanks.